# How to create vector to store addresses of all children?

Tags: c++, class, vector, parent-child

I am trying to create a basic game engine in C++ and I want an `Engine` object to be able to loop through all the `GameObject` children to run their update methods, to do this I want to use a vector of all children within the `Engine` class.

## For example:

*This is similar to what I have been trying to do:*

**Parent Engine Class**

```
class Engine {
public:
    Engine() {};

    std::vector<GameObject> GameObjects; //Vector to store all GameObjects

    void AddNewObject(GameObject& obj) {
        GameObjects.push_back(obj); //Add new object to the vector array
    }

    void Run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.size(); i++) {
            GameObjects[i].Update(); //Run the update method of each GameObject
        }
    }
}
```

**GameObject Child Class**

```
class GameObject : public Engine {
public:
    GameObject() {}

    void Update() {
        //Do stuff
    }

}
```

**Main code loop**

```
int main(void) {
  Engine engine;
  
  GameObject object;

  engine.AddNewObject(object); //Add object

  engine.run();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: `GameObject` should probably not be a child of `Engine`. That implies that every single object in your game is in fact its own game engine, which is less than sensible. Aside from that and some possible [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) if you plan to subclass `GameObject` (which can be fixed with a good old-fashioned `unique_ptr`), I don't see any problems here.

Comment: be very cautios about storing objects in containers. it works but make sure you dont create copies. I have seen lots of code that has multilple copies of the 'same' object that are updatied into different startes. Better to put smart ptr into the vecto

Comment: You have a plan. (Actually, I see two plans -- one involving "a vector of all children" and one involving a vector of addresses of all children.) So go for it. What's the question? Did you run into a problem? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thanks for the advice, I tried it out and it cut the number of errors in half, along with Brad 's advice it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First, your vector needs to be a vector of references or pointers, otherwise `GameObjects.push_back(obj);` makes a copy of `obj` to place into the vector (unless you [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) it) and [polymorphism](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-polymorphism/) won't work (you can't hold subclasses of `GameObject`).

How you approach this depends on which object you want to own the memory associated with each `GameObject`. A trivial fix is is by using a vector of pointers:

```cpp
class Engine {
    public:
        Engine() {};
    
        std::vector<GameObject*> GameObjects; //Vector to store all GameObjects
    
        void AddNewObject(GameObject& obj) {
            GameObjects.push_back(&obj); //Add new object to the vector array
        }
    
        void Run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.size(); i++) {
                GameObjects[i]->Update(); //Run the update method of each GameObject
            }
        }
    }
```

However, with modern, C++ you would want to probably use a smart pointer like [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```cpp
class Engine {
    public:
        Engine() {};
    
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> GameObjects; //Vector to store all GameObjects
    
        void AddNewObject(std::unique_ptr<GameObject> obj) {
            GameObjects.push_back(std::move(obj)); //Add new object to the vector array
        }
    
        void Run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.size(); i++) {
                GameObjects[i]->Update(); //Run the update method of each GameObject
            }
        }
    }
```

By using a unique pointer, you would have to change your other code:

```cpp
int main(void) {
  Engine engine;
  
  std::unique_ptr<GameObject> object = std::make_unique<GameObject>();

  // Transfers memory ownership of `object` into `engine`
  engine.AddNewObject(std::move(object)); //Add object

  engine.run();
}
```

Lastly, your class hierarchy looks invalid. You probably don't need or want `GameObject` to be a subclass of Engine since they don't share anything in common. `GameObject` may likely be a good base class itself and other game objects would inherit it.

Comment: I took your advice of removing `GameObject` as a child of `Engine` and also fixing my issue of not making the vector a pointer. Seems to of fixed the issue.